# Downscaling inline images in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, images

I used to be able to scale down an inline image in org-mode with

```
#+attr_html: :width 650 px
[[file:~/org/def/202a3-9.jpeg]]
```

But now it doesn't work anymore, presumably because of an update to 8.3.5.  What to do?

Comment: What you have will scale the images in HTML exports, not in the org buffer. Your lack of info on the org/emacs versions when things worked and the same when things did not work cannot help anyone help you on this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

set option in your emacs init file:

```
(setq org-image-actual-width nil)
```

And add this property upon image link:

```
#+NAME: fig:figure name
#+CAPTION: figure name
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 200
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 2.0in
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 200
[[file:./file.png]]
```

The width value `200` and `2.0in` can be any inch number value if you want.

Comment: I sometimes set the org-image-actual-width on a per-file basis.

Comment: Is it not possible to set the `:width` attribute for all formats at once?

Comment: `#+NAME` does not do anything for me. The label of the figure is still automatically generated...

Comment: You can use Buffer local scope attribute. I don't know is there any option can do this. But you can explore the source code.

Comment: It's `#+NAME:` not `#+NAME`, don't emit the `:`.

Comment: If you don't want html/latex export. `#+ATTR_ORG: :width <yourValue>` is enough.

Comment: Is it possible to put similar command in `.emac.d` and resize globally..?

Comment: There is an Org Mode option `org-image-actual-width` for this.

Comment: What does `200/250/300/400/500/600` mean? The inline mode just uses the smallest size (200) for me.

Comment: The `200/250/300/400/500/600` means size in inch unit. You can use any value like `200`, `500` etc. I will update answer.

Answer (score -2):

Some testing seem to show that just adding a space before the `#` solve the problem. It look like a bug. May be you should report it to the org-list.

Comment: Oddly that doesn't work for me.

Comment: -- with version 8.3.5.

Comment: I've version `8.3.4`